# How do i Send email to Email addresses after Database is saved (MongoDB/ Node.JS / NodeMailer)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nodemailer

I am trying to work on a scenario where ,  user registers and it sends Email to both the user and the admin. I am working on this using node.JS / nodemailer/ MongodDB and the likes. Now I want to do something like this.
Once the register button is clicked, it saves data to the Database, then sends the email to both parties. The data is saved to the Database, no issues but the email part does not Work. My source code is looking thus

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'),
    bcrypt = require('bcrypt'),
    nodemailer = require('nodemailer'),
    User = mongoose.model('User');

    function dispatch_emails(admin_email, user_email, fullname, company_name){
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service:'gmail',
            host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
            port:'587',
            auth:{
                user: '***************@gmail.com',
                pass: '**************'
            },
            secureConnection: 'false',
            tls: {
                ciphers: 'SSLv3',
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            }
        });

        const mailOptions = {
            from :'**************@gmail.com',
            to: user_email,
            subject: 'Account Registration Successful!',
            html : '<h3>Attention,'+fullname+' , </h3><p><h3>Your Account has been successfully setup.</h3></p><p> Please allow a maximum of 24 - 48 Hours for Review and succesful setup and approval of your online account.</p></br>Regards,</br> Online Services.'
        };

        const AdminNotifyEmail = {
            from :'**************@gmail.com',
            to: admin_email,
            subject: 'Account Registration for '+user_email+', with Fullname : '+fullname+' ('+company_name+')',
            html : '<h3>Attention Admin , </h3><p>A new User has registered his Access with the following Information: </br> <strong>Username : '+user_email+'</strong></br><strong>Company Name : '+company_name+'</strong></br><strong>Date of Registration : '+Date.Now+'</strong></p>'
        };
    
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(error,info){
            if(error)throw error;
            return res.send({error:false, data: info, message: 'OK'});
        })

        transporter.sendMail(AdminNotifyEmail,function(error,info){
            if(error)throw error;
            return res.send({error:false, data: info, message: 'OK'});
        })
    
    }

exports.register = function(req,res){
    var admin_email = req.body.admin_email;
    var newUser = new User(req.body);
    newUser.hash_password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);
    newUser.save(function(err,user){
        if(err){
            return res.status(400).send({
                message : err
            });
        }else{
            dispatch_emails(admin_email, newUser.user_email, newUser.fullname, newUser.company_name);
            user.hash_password = undefined;
            return res.json(user);
        }
    })
};

exports.sign_in = function(req,res){
    User.findOne({
        email : req.body.email
    },function(err,user){
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!user || !user.comparePassword(req.body.password)){
            return res.status(401).json({message: 'Cannot Login, Authentication Failed'})
        }
        return res.json({token :jwt.sign({email: user.email, fullname: user.fullname, _id: user._id}, 'RESTFULAPI')})
    })
};

exports.loginRequired = function(req,res,next){
    if(req.user){
        next();
    }else{
        return res.status(401).json({message: 'unauthorized User'});
    }
};

exports.profile = function(req,res,next){
    if(req.user){
        req.send(req.user);
        next();
    }else{
        return res.status(401).json({message: 'Invalid Token'});
    }
}
```

The data is saved to the database without trouble, just this Email. How do i fix this, any ideas?

Comment: do you receive any feedback from `return res.json(user);`? Can you perhaps try to catch any error throw from `dispatch_emails` function

Answer (score 0):

After a struggle i have been able to get it to send Emails

Changing from

```
exports.register = function(req,res){
    var admin_email = req.body.admin_email;
    var newUser = new User(req.body);
    newUser.hash_password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);
    newUser.save(function(err,user){
        if(err){
            return res.status(400).send({
                message : err
            });
        }else{
            dispatch_emails(admin_email, newUser.user_email, newUser.fullname, newUser.company_name);
            user.hash_password = undefined;
            return res.json(user);
        }
    })
};
```

To this

```
exports.register = function(req,res){
    var admin_email = req.body.admin_email;
    var newUser = new User();
    newUser.company_name = req.body.company_name;
    newUser.fullname = req.body.fullname;
    newUser.user_email = req.body.user_email;
    newUser.phone_number = req.body.phone_number;
    newUser.timezone = req.body.timezone;
    newUser.hash_password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);
    newUser.save(function(err,user){
        if(err){
            return res.status(400).send({
                message : err
            });
        }else{
            dispatch_emails(admin_email, newUser.user_email, newUser.fullname, newUser.company_name);
            user.hash_password = undefined;
            return res.json(user);
        }
    })
};
```

And the whole Information sends to the emails without worries. Thanks everyone.

Hopefully it can help someone in Future.